# laravel 5 Query Builder error "must be of the type array, object given"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Ok so i am trying to perform a mysql query to join to tables and return the results.

So in my controller i have an array of serviceIDs that when print_r() looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50707
    [1] => 50709
)
```

The name of this array is $serviceIDS

Okay Then i now call a function from one of my models. This is a scope as seen below:

```
$services = Services::getWatchListInfo($serviceIDS)->get();
```

This is the scope function in my model:

```
public function scopegetWatchListInfo($serviceIDS){

    $services = DB::table('services')
                ->join('reviews','services.serviceID','=','reviews.serviceID')
                ->select('services.name','services.type','services.review_count_approved','reviews.escalate','reviews.average_rating')
                ->whereIn('serviceID',$serviceIDS);
    return $services;
}
```

Okay so this should get results from both my services and reviews table where service id is in the array.

Instead i am getting the following error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called in /Users/user/sites/informatics-2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 311 and defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using Eloquent scopes correctly. If you [read the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes), you're attempting to use a Dynamic Scope, so you need to define your scope as:

```
/**
 * getWatchList Eloquent Scope
 * 
 * @param  object $query
 * @param  array  $servicesIDS
 * @return object $query
 */
public function scopegetWatchListInfo($query, $serviceIDS = []) {
    return $query
        ->join('reviews','services.serviceID','=','reviews.serviceID')
        ->select('services.name','services.type','services.review_count_approved','reviews.escalate','reviews.average_rating')
        ->whereIn('serviceID', $serviceIDS);
}
```

The `DB::table('services')` should not be necessary if you're defining a Scope within your `Services` model (because the `services` table is [automatically handled by Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> Now, let's look at an example `Flight` model class, which we will use to retrieve and store information from our `flights` database table

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked! however the results i get back are actually 6 , when only 2 ids went in. So its bring back the same 2 results 3 times which is strange

Comment: I think that's probably happening due to `join()` statement. You can check the SQL query being generated by changing `->get()` to `->toSql()`. If you put that SQL into PHPMyAdmin (or whatever SQL app you're using), you'll be able to check the SQL that's being generated, and determine how to write the correct `JOIN` statement.

Comment: Thanks, it does the same in phpmyadmin, but i dont know why aha :(

Comment: Create a new question on StackOverflow, with your database structure, and your SQL. I (or someone else), will be able to help you with it.

Comment: its fine now i managed to sort it out. Thanks for the help :)